# No data returned to jquery datatables from ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

This is my first try with `datatables`.  I'd like to call an `ajax` function to return data from the database (`MariaDB`) and populate the `rows` and `cells` of an existing `table` in the `php` file.

The simplified version of the code regarding datafields is this:

```
$('#tbl_resultados').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/apls/indicadores/indic_acess.php",
        "sAjaxDataProp": "data",
        "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
        request = $.ajax({
              "dataType": 'json', 
              "type": "GET", 
              "url": sSource, 
              "data":{ 
                  "fn": "lines",
                  "indic_per": indic_per,
                        },
              "success": fnCallback
            });
      },

      "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "id"},
            { "mDataProp": "per"},
                 ],
    } );
```

I've tried with and without `"bServerSide": true,` but can't get data to be displayed in the `table`.  `Firebug` returns `TypeError: aData is undefined`.

Following what is being said in [the example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/ajax.html) I've built a function in `php` that returns a `json` like structure.

```
function getLines()
{                                                                                               
echo "{ \"aData\":[
    [
         \"25983\",
         \"2010\"
    ],                                         
    [
        \"90420\",
        \"2011\"
    ]
    ]
    }";
}
```

Like I said, I've no experience with `datatables` don't know whether to use `aData` or `aaData`, or what to try more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other example for ajax source :
http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

It says :
`DataTables expects an object with an array called "aaData" with the data source.`

Here is some of their ajax return :

```
{ "aaData": [
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 4.0","Win 95+","4","X"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 5.0","Win 95+","5","C"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 5.5","Win 95+","5.5","A"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 6","Win 98+","6","A"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 7","Win XP SP2+","7","A"],
    .
    .
    .
    ["Misc","Links","Text only","-","X"],
    ["Misc","Lynx","Text only","-","X"],
    ["Misc","IE Mobile","Windows Mobile 6","-","C"],
    ["Misc","PSP browser","PSP","-","C"],
    ["Other browsers","All others","-","-","U"]
] }
```

On my side, I always use `aaData` to initiate table data.
Beside this, you could return more options (like `sEcho`, `iTotalRecords`, `iTotalDisplayRecords`, ...) in order to complete your rendering.

Comment: There's something I must be missing... I used your example. In the `getLines` `Php` function did a `echo "your answer";` and escaped the quotes.  In firebug, as a response to the `http` `GET` method there's: `{ "aaData": [
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 4.0","Win 95+","4"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 5.0","Win 95+","5"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 5.5","Win 95+","5.5"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 6","Win 98+","6"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 7","Win XP SP2+","7"]
] }`.  But still get a `TypeError: aData is undefined` error.

Comment: Did you try to start from the example (by copying the source code), and tried to replace what you need ?

Comment: The example is not like what I intend to do: `"sAjaxSource": '../examples_support/json_source.txt'` instead of using an `ajax` call to a php function.

Answer (score 0):

Datatables.net examples don't work with MariaDB server (same for login using users different form root ~ old password encryption). I don't know why it doesn't, but it doesn't respond any data (ajax). Tested on Windows MariaDB server.

Solution: install a MySQL server service/daemon on different port if you don't want to uninstall MariaDB server, and you migrate (export/import) data.

Comment: Real solution: Make explicit charset definition (ex: charset=utf8) on MariaDB/MySQL connectionString.